# Why am I getting [object Object] when passing in data to a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a rather frustrating scenario where this code works perfectly when used on its own but if i try to put it inside another directive the console.log outputs [object Object] instead of the actual object. I can't figure out whats going on.

js

```
 (function () {

  'use strict';

    angular.module('stn-core')
        .directive('htmlContent', htmlContent);

  function htmlContent () {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: 'content-blocks/html-content/html-content.html',
      scope: {
        data: "="
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.data);
        scope.componentName = 'html-content';
      }
    };
  }

})();
```

template

```
{{data | json}}
<div class="html-content">
    <div ng-bind-html="data.data[data.data.type]"></div>
</div>
```

Location of directive causing the problem (another directive template)

```
<div class="conference-location">
  <html-content data="data.topHtml" class="con-location-html1 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 sol-xs-12"></html-content>
  <div ng-bind-html="data.bottomHtml" class="con-location-html2  col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
       ng-class="{'col-lg-6 col-md-6':width< 100, 'col-lg-8 col-md-7':width === 100}"></div>
  <div class="conference-location-widget  col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
       ng-class="{'col-lg-6 col-md-6': width < 100, 'col-lg-4 col-md-5':width===100}">
    <stn-location data="data.conference"></stn-location>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you using this htmlContent directive in html.

Comment: Edited to show where the directive is

Comment: data.topHtml will be having html string, right?

Comment: No it's an object. That's the whole point.

Comment: Okay so you're getting as object but you're expecting it to be string.

Comment: No. I am passing an object in. This usually works. What I am seeing is that when this directive is placed within another directive the object argument is interpreted as the string '[object Object]'

Answer (score 0):

You need to console it as string and to convert into string you can use `stringify` method of JSON object.

Try as below:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(scope.data));
```

Comment: That's not really good enough, maybe I didn't explain properly, sometimes the directive interprets the 'data' argument as a js object that can be navigated and used (as it should) but in the case I have mentioned it appears as the string '[object Object]'

Answer (score 0):

So basically there was an issue with the names of the properties I was using. If I passed in 'data' instead of 'data.topHtml' I noticed that the object then logged as this

```
data : {
 topHtml: '[object Object]'
}
```

The issue appears to occur when the name used includes capital letters and even minus signs. I fixed it by changing the name to tophtml and updating the templates to use that instead.